# CSS Override in Rails Application

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, sass

I am trying to override the white-space: nowrap in my table cell formatting in my Rails application, but am unable to do so no matter how I try.  Here is the situation:

this is the top of my application.sass file:

```
//= require_self
//= require datatable_styles
//= require calendar
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
```

As you can see, I require self before I require datatable_styles.  datatable_styles.sass has the following rule pertaining to the table th td white-space:

```
td, th
  white-space: nowrap
```

In most cases this works so that is not the issue.  However, in one of my tables, I have a 'notes' field being displayed in a table cell that needs to have the white-space set to wrap, since it can have multiple long sentences.  Here is how I am trying to override it:

this is my Rails view in HAML that has the notes field:

```
= render 'shared_projects/secondary_nav'
%h3
  Billable Notes for - #{@project.name}
%table.display.table.table-striped.table-bordered
  %thead
    %tr
      %th.date Date
      %th.notes Notes
  %tbody
    - @notes_array.each do |n|
      %tr
        %td.date
          = n[0]
        %td#billables-comments
          = n[1]
```

See the #billables-comments id on the 'td' cell?  I have a corresponding CSS rule in my application.sass file after the require statements as shown below:

```
td#billables-comments
  white-space: wrap
```

But that has no effect, the white-space: wrap rule defined in the datatable_styles.sass file is always trumping the more specific td#billables-comments defined in application.sass file.  I have tried various combinations for the cell rule definition, e.g., defining #billables-comments by itself.  Putting !important in-front of wrap like so:

```
td#billables-comments
  white-space: !important wrap
```

But nothing seems to work.

P.S. In response to the question asked below:  Yes I did try to inspect this element in Google Chrome and I see the following:

```
media="all"
td#billables-comments {
white-space: !important wrap;
}
```

However, the white-space line has a strike-through it indicating that this rule is being overridden by the datatable_styles rule shown below:

```
media="all"
td, th {
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

which has no strike-through indicating that this rule is in effect.  When I click on the checkbox on white-spaces' left and deselect it instructing Chrome to undefine the rule, the text wraps fine then.  But I am manipulating the CSS under the hood then.  And that is not the solution :(

Comment: Did you try inspecting the element in question to see if your more specific styles even exist?

Comment: Yes. I did.  Unfortunately, it is shown is being overriden as below:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default state for the white-space property is `normal`, not `wrap`.

Note that running your CSS through the validator would have caught this error for you.  Chrome's inspector will cross out all invalid/unknown properties, not just ones that are being overwritten elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you kind sir.  It worked.  Where and how do I find a CSS validator?